# How to set value width percent in javascript style?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a sample code:

```
<div id="test-content"></div>
<script>
var width = 100;
document.getElementById('test-content').style.width = width+ '%';
</script>
```

Error can't add style 100% width, how to fix it

Comment: Where are u getting error - can u demonstrate? This code should work fine as it is

Comment: I also tried it and it worked fine.

Comment: Yep, have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ps5LC/ should work as it is.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ps5LC/1/ It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use style.setProperty("width", "100%")

Comment: this fixed it for me. i was trying to set 100% height but on iOS Safari 10 `el.style.height = '100%'` would break it.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery, you can do that like this:

```
<script>
var width = 100;
$('#test-content').css('width', width + '%');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
document.getElementById('div_register').setAttribute("style","width:50%");
```